# How do I use **kwargs in Python 3 class __init__ function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am writing a class in Python 3 that I want to be able to take various keyword arguments from the user and to store these values for later use in class methods. An example code would be something like this:

```
class MathematicalModel:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, **kwargs):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = kwarg1
        self.var5 = kwarg2
        self.var6 = kwarg6

    def calculation1(self):
        x = self.var1 + self.var2 + self.var3
        return x

    def calculation2(self):
        y = self.var1 * self.var2 * var3
        return y

class MathematicalModelExtended(MathematicalModel):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, **kwargs):
        super.__init__(self, var1, var2, var3, **kwargs)

    def calculation1(self):
        '''Overrides calculation1 method from parent DoThis'''
        x = (self.var1 + self.var2 + self.var3) / self.kwarg1
        return x

    def calculation2(self):
        '''Overrides calculation2 method from parent DoThis'''
        y = (self.var1 * self.var2 * self.var3) / (self.kwarg1 + self.kwarg2)
        return y

a = MathematicalModel(1, 2, 3)
b = MathematicalModelExtended(1, 2, 3, var4 = 4, var5 = 5, var6 = 6)
```

However I am not sure how this works, for a few reasons:
a) What if the user doesn't put an argument for b or c, or even a for that matter? Then the code will throw an error, so I am not sure how to initialize these attributes in that case.
b) How do I access the values associated with the keywords, when I don't know what keyword argument the user passed beforehand?

I plan to use the variables in mathematical formulas. Some variables (not included in `kwargs`) will be used in every formula, whereas others (the ones in `kwargs`) will only be used in other formulas. I plan to wrap `MathematicalModel` in another class like-so `MathematicalModelExtended(MathematicalModel)` in order to achieve that.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain the last part "How do I access the values associated with the keywords, when **I don't know what keyword argument the user passed beforehand**?" Also, what are `a`, `b`, and `c` supposed to represent? Similarly, what are `key1`, `key2`, and `key3`? Are you looking for `*args` or `**kwargs`?

Comment: For example, the user could pass any keyword for the kwargs. They can say a=1 or a1=1 or a2=1. So how can I initialize these values to be used later on with self.key=value? I am looking for `**kwargs` because I would like these to be keyworded arguments.

Comment: Please add a code example that clearly shows what you are trying to do. It doesn't have to work right, but it's difficult to guess at what classes like `DoThis` and `NowDoThis` are supposed to do and how they are getting called or used. There is a lot of value in having generic functions and classes, but in this case, the lack of clarity is making it difficult to provide a good answer for your question.

Comment: I added more code to better show what exactly it is I want to do (though like you said, it is by no means correct).

Comment: Okay, now the question I have is if the function call for `calculation1` and `calculation2` should be passed the arguments or if they're supposed to be taken from the logic contained in the `__init__` function? I'm going to assume you don't intend to pass all the arguments again, otherwise OOP isn't a good use case here. I'm also curious if `DoThis` and `NowDoThis` are meant to imply a sequence or if `DoThis` and `DoThisWithMoreOptions` would be a better fit. This is what i meant when i said the generic function and class names aren't helping provide a good answer.

Comment: Correct, those functions are supposed to take the variables from the __init__ method. I edited my code to reflect that. Sorry, DoThis and DoThisWithMoreOptions are better, I actually haven't decided names for these classes yet but I might call them something like ```MathematicalModel``` and ```MathematicalModelExtended```. I changed the code to reflect this as well.

Comment: ``**kwargs`` are *variadic* keyword arguments – meaning their count is arbitrary. Using explicit fields of ``kwargs``, e.g. ``self.kwarg1``, doesn't make any sense – the very point of ``**kwargs`` is that each specific keyword argument may or may not exist. In other words, if you expect a specific ``kwarg1`` it is by definition not variadic.

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi, I realize that, I just listed out potential ```kwargs``` to show an example of what I want to do with these arguments. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## General kwargs ideas

When you load variables with `self.var = value`, it adds it to an internal dictionary that can be accessed with `self.__dict__`.

```
class Foo1:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.a = kwargs['a']
        self.b = kwargs['b']

foo1 = Foo1(a=1, b=2)
print(foo1.a)  # 1
print(foo1.b)  # 2
print(foo1.__dict__)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

If you want to allow for arbitrary arguments, you can leverage the fact that `kwargs` is also a dictionary and use the `update()` function.

```
class Foo2:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

foo2 = Foo2(some_random_variable=1, whatever_the_user_supplies=2)
print(foo2.some_random_variable)  # 1
print(foo2.whatever_the_user_supplies)  # 2
print(foo2.__dict__)  # {'some_random_variable': 1, 'whatever_the_user_supplies': 2}
```

This will prevent you from getting an error when you try to store a value that isn't there

```
class Foo3:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.a = kwargs['a']
        self.b = kwargs['b']

foo3 = Foo3(a=1)  # KeyError: 'b'
```

If you wanted to ensure that variables `a` or `b` were set in the class regardless of what the user supplied, you could create class attributes or use `kwargs.get()`

```
class Foo4:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.a = kwargs.get('a', None)
        self.b = kwargs.get('b', None)

foo4 = Foo4(a=1)
print(foo4.a)  # 1
print(foo4.b)  # None
print(foo4.__dict__)  # {'a': 1, 'b': None}
```

However, with this method, the variables belong to the class rather than the instance. This is why you see `foo5.b` return a string, but it's not in `foo5.__dict__`.

```
class Foo5:

    a = 'Initial Value for A'
    b = 'Initial Value for B'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

foo5 = Foo5(a=1)
print(foo5.a)  # 1
print(foo5.b)  # Initial Value for B
print(foo5.__dict__)  # {'a': 1}
```

If you are giving the users the freedom to specify any `kwargs` they want, you can iterate through the `__dict__` in a function.

```
class Foo6:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def do_something(self):
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            print(f"{k} -> {v}")

foo6 = Foo6(some_random_variable=1, whatever_the_user_supplies=2)
foo6.do_something()
# some_random_variable -> 1
# whatever_the_user_supplies -> 2
```

However, depending on whatever else you have going on in your class, you might end up with a lot more instance attributes than the user supplied. Therefore, it might be good to have the user supply a dictionary as an argument.

```
class Foo7:

    def __init__(self, user_vars):
        self.user_vars  = user_vars

    def do_something(self):
        for k, v in self.user_vars.items():
            print(f"{k} -> {v}")

foo7 = Foo7({'some_random_variable': 1, 'whatever_the_user_supplies': 2})
foo7.do_something()
# some_random_variable -> 1
# whatever_the_user_supplies -> 2
```

## Addressing your code

With your updated code, I would suggest using the `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` method. Then you can either raise an error when you don't encounter variable you're relying on (`option1` method) or you can have a default value for the variable incase it's not defined (`option2` method)

```
class MathematicalModel:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, **kwargs):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)  # Store all the extra variables


class MathematicalModelExtended(MathematicalModel):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(var1, var2, var3, **kwargs)

    def option1(self):
        # Trap error if you need var4 to be specified
        if 'var4' not in self.__dict__:
            raise ValueError("Please provide value for var4")

        x = (self.var1 + self.var2 + self.var3) / self.var4
        return x

    def option2(self):
        # Use .get() to provide a default value when the user does not provide it.
        _var4 = self.__dict__.get('var4', 1)

        x = (self.var1 + self.var2 + self.var3) / self.var4
        return x


a = MathematicalModel(1, 2, 3)
b = MathematicalModelExtended(1, 2, 3, var4=4, var5=5, var6=6)
print(b.option1())  # 1.5
print(b.option2())  # 1.5
```

Granted, if `MathematicalModel` will never use anything other than `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`, there's no point in passing the `kwargs`.

```
class MathematicalModel:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, **kwargs):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3

class MathematicalModelExtended(MathematicalModel):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(var1, var2, var3)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def option1(self):
        # Trap error if you need var4 to be specified
        if 'var4' not in self.__dict__:
            raise ValueError("Please provide value for var4")

        x = (self.var1 + self.var2 + self.var3) / self.var4
        return x

    def option2(self):
        # Use .get() to provide a default value when the user does not provide it.
        _var4 = self.__dict__.get('var4', 1)

        x = (self.var1 + self.var2 + self.var3) / self.var4
        return x


a = MathematicalModel(1, 2, 3)
b = MathematicalModelExtended(1, 2, 3, var4=4, var5=5, var6=6)
print(b.option1())  # 1.5
print(b.option2())  # 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not sure I understand. In the first part of your reply, is __dict__ the internal dictionary created when **kwargs is passed as an argument? Second, I don't understand, is defining the class values and then overriding them later just so that they have specific names?

Comment: I think my confusion with the second method is that why would I instantiate attributes that may or may not be used? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: My confusion is why you're looking to allow arbitrary kwargs defined by the user and how you plan on using them. I could understand if you're just shepherding them to another class or function called within your class, but I don't sense that's what you're doing. So, if you need to ensure that certain variables are accessible regardless of what the user enters, it helps to define them ahead of time in the class or instance. I'd use the `Foo7` approach and keep all the user's input contained to a single variable. Then you can see exactly what they provided and isolate it from critical functions

Comment: " I could understand if you're just shepherding them to another class or function called within your class, but I don't sense that's what you're doing" Actually that is what I plan to do. The user will supply numbers that are certain variables in a mathematical formula (but not all formulas in all instances will need these variables). So that is why I want to define them as instance variables

Comment: Are you wrapping a class with `class Foo(OtherClass)`? or are you calling the class within your class? Please update your question to make it a little more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying before. I plan to wrap a class and use inheritance to perform the calculations with the extra variables that aren't always used. I updated my post with the full explanation. Thanks so much for sticking with me here, I'm pretty new to OOP and the whole args vs. kwargs thing.

Comment: I looked at your updated answer, since ```MathematicalModel``` never uses ```kwargs```, is only needs to be passed in as an argument in ```MathematicalModelExtended```?

Comment: It depends on what `MathematicalModel` is, but if it's not going to use the additional arguments, then there's no point in passing extra arguments to it.